# Is it possible for users to request vPMU/arch_perfmon feature on GCP instances for profiling purpose?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I asked the PCM community here (https://github.com/opcm/pcm/discussions/257) and they thought this might be the only solution to get PCM running on GCP. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to the [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/opcm/pcm/discussions/257):

> GCP needs to enable arch_perfmon/vPMU feature to allow collection of
> core perfmon counters. AWS did it for some virtualized instances and
> PCM works on those:
>
> C5 (including c5n and c5dn): 9xlarge, 12xlarge, 18xlarge, 24xlarge M5
> (including m5n, m5dn, m5zn): 12xlarge, 24xlarge R5 (including r5n,
> r5dn, r5b): 8xlarge, 12xlarge

**To solve your issue**, you should file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under [this component](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559755). Keep in mind that the feature request has to be analyzed and considered by the product team and there's no ETA for it to be delivered.